# В чем разница forward() и include() у RequestDispatcher?

Tags: java, jsp, servlet

Везде написано что `include` включает контент ресурса (сервлет, `JSP` или `HTML` страница) в ответ. Но не понятно контент **какого**(где источник) ресурса? Два варианта:

```
request.getRequestDispatcher(".../index.jsp").forward(request, response);
request.getRequestDispatcher(".../index.jsp").include(request, response);
```

И в том и другом случае мы просто получим страницу `index.jsp`. О каких ресурсах идет речь кроме тех которые указаны в пути в `getRequestDispatcher`?
Другими словами что нужно сделать чтобы увидеть разницу в поведении методов `forward` и `include`? Спасибо.

Comment: Попробуйте после forward и после include ещё что-нибудь вывести в response. И посмотрите что получится. Попробуйте вывести в response до вызова forward и include. Что произойдёт в этом случае?

Comment: @Sergey что значит _вывести в response_ в смысле в параметры что-нибудь записать?

Comment: response.getOutputStream().println("bla-bla-bla");

Comment: include используется чтобы вставить вывод другого сервлета в текущий. forward позволяет провести предварительную обработку запроса и потом полностью передать управление другому сервлету.